# What is the diff between trigger and Cursor?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle

I Am New in Sql.............. I Dont Know About Diff

So Plz Suggest Me

Different Between "**Trigger**" and "**cursor**"

Thanks In Advance

Comment: To me, this sounds like "what is the difference between an apple and a hammer?" They are both things that fit into your hand, but that's about it. Next time, read just a little bit of documentation and this very obvious difference will be clear to you.

Comment: You should delete this question...some cursory research would provide your answer.

Comment: Sorry, this question has answers and cannot be deleted; flag it for moderator attention instead.

Comment: Okay, I was under the impression that you could delete a question if the answers were not upvoted...

Answer (score 4):

Simple, `TRIGGER` is a special block of code on the table that fires when an event `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and/or `DELETE` happens on the table.

`CURSOR` a control structure used in databases to go through the database records. It is very similar to the iterator (*eg. FOR LOOP*) provided by many programming languages.